# Finding xml file in a solutionexplorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio

i have a big solution containing that much projects..i need to find

a specific xml file in that solution example "sample.xml".Using ctrl+shift
+F we cant find the specific xml file ..Is there any shortcuts for finding
xml file in solution explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Resharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) it gives you a lot of useful shortcuts for code navigation and more.

Comment: other than that  because i dont know whether my company will allow or not